# Highlighting routes using plugin like ATLAS/EASY PRINT

Tags: mapinfo

I use Atlas to auto generate my maps.  Every "route" has a coverage.
At times the "routes" are too close, so the lines cross and it is impossible to make out a specific "route". I really need some advice on this please.

Atlas already jumps from "route" to "route" take the .jpeg images for me.

I tried to use EASY PRINT but was unsuccessful.

[image: example]

The black is what I get by default. The red is what I would like to show for that "route" with the highlighted "route" name (red added with paint).

So, in short words, **when that map gets generated for that "route" it should be highlighted and the rest of the "routes" must stay black.**  This needs to be done automatically: I have too many maps to do this manually.

Comment: Sorry guys forgot to say that it still got to stay auto generate
have to many maps to do single by single manually

Comment: The question is tagged "mapinfo" but it sounds a lot like you are using QGIS. Can you clarify?